# How to make "background-size" work in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

I am building a website for newer browsers, but I want it to look decent in IE8 too. Everything was OK, until I ran into a problem. I found that `background-size` is not working in IE8. After some research I was able to find some sort of "hack", but it didn't work for me.

Maybe I am doing something wrong; please take a look at this code and maybe suggest a solution that will fix background sizing in IE8, (preferably a CSS solution).

```
.logo {
    width: 190px;
    height: 204px;
    background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 190px 204px;

    /** This is the so called IE8 hack, but it doesn't seem to work **/

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/logo.png',sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/logo.pn',sizingMethod='scale')";

    /** End of Hack */

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;
    margin: -73px 0 0 405px;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the latest `-ms-filter` declaration, "src='../img/logo.pn'" instead of "src='../img/logo.png'". Probably this is the reason it doesn't work? Also, there is actually no need to specify both `filter` and `-ms-filter`, all shipped versions of IE8 support both, so you can entirely drop the latter one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is Retina screens, right? Since the market share of that kind of screen isn't that big, I would prefer using a "standard" image first and then replace it by a high-resolution if needed.

You can do it with [Retina.js](http://retinajs.com/) for example.

Or you can simply use an image tag instead. It will work on IE8. Don't forget to define the width & height properties.

```
<a href="/" class="logo">
  <img src="img/logo.png" width="190" height="204" alt="Bryuvers">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't supports Background-size property of CSS3. But you can have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. This may help you.